# issue with form submit of .dialogf of jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I send '`return true`' to my submit button, if i have open .dialog of jQuery on onclick even of submit button.
I want to return true to my submit button on dialog's 'OK' button. so that my form get submit.

```
<form>
<input type='submit' name='btn1' onclick='javascript:return test()' />
</form>

function test(){
$('#testDiv').dialog('open');
}
```

Dialog have 2 buttons 'OK' & 'cancel'

Comment: If you're already using jQuery, I don't understand why you'd want to use the onclick attribute to bind your event. Look into the `.submit()` function, or use a button (instead of input with submit type) and use `.on()` to bind the click event.

Comment: is it work ot not ? ................

Comment: I have to write .Submit()...then it worked

Comment: @Greg Pettit : thanks ...that worked....Please add it as ur answer to this questions

Comment: @PoonamBhatt Done! Embarrassingly, I'm usually the one who looks at people's "answers in comments" and think to myself, "Why don't you just make that an answer?" ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already using jQuery, don't use the `onclick` attribute to bind your event.

Look into the `.submit()` function (which intercepts a normal submit event), or just use a `button` element (instead of `input` with submit type) and use `.on()` to bind the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't below work?

```
function test(){
$('#testDiv').dialog('open');
return true;
}
```

In Javascript below is what I do

```
 <html>
 <script language="Javascript">

 function checkMe() {
 if (false) {
 return false;
 }

 return true;
 }

 </script>
 <body>

 <form action="doAction">
 // form content here

 <input type=submit value="Submit" onClick="return checkMe()">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as below, you can even customize buttons text as per your wish.

```
$("#testDiv").dialog({ buttons: [
    {
        text: "Ok",
        click: function() { return true; };
    },

    {
        text: "cancel",
        click: function() { return false; };
    }
] });
```